# How to run Spring Data Cassandra 2.2.1 with Cassandra 2.1.9?

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I've developed a new application with Spring Data Cassandra 2.2.1 and want to run it against a Cassandra 2.1.9 server (old, I know). But we get the error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnsupportedProtocolVersionException: Host does not support protocol version V4 but V3
```

The [Spring Data Cassandra manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/) claims that Spring Data 2.2.1 needs at least Cassandra 2.1, so this *should* work but it doesn't. The only cassandra-specific dependency we include is `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra`

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can configure the protocol version the driver uses. The default with Spring Boot Cassandra 2.2.1 and `com.datastax.driver.core` 3.7.2 is V4, i.e. at least Cassandra 2.2.0.

To configure it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
  @Value("${cassandra.protocolVersion}")
  private Integer protocolVersion;
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public ProtocolVersion getProtocolVersion() {
    return ProtocolVersion.fromInt(protocolVersion);
  }
}
```

And e.g. in your `application.yml` for Cassandra 2.1.9:

```
cassandra.protocolVersion: 3
```